# Из pdf в jpg с помощью Python

Tags: python, pdf, jpeg

Как перевести pdf в jpg с помощью Python?

Comment: А если в гугл ввести `python pdf to image`, то найдете, что искали? ;)

Comment: pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?

Comment: Посмотрите там про установки на виндовс: https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image#windows , ошибка об этом и говорит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установка нужной библиотеки

```
pip3 install pdf2image
```

Собственно решение

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
pages = convert_from_path('pdf_file', 500)
for i, page in enumerate(pages):
    page.save(f'out{i}.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

Comment: Добавили бы хотя бы минимум описания? К первой строке, что это установка библиотеки, ко второму блоку - что собственно решение

Comment: pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?